# Bootstrap selected item value for DropDown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the values of my two bootstrap dropdown menus selectable. The site can be viewed [here](http://dropdown.raynes.io).

As you can see I have customised the dropdown menu's slightly within the CSS.

HTML:

```
        <!-- City Dropdown -->
        <div class="btn-group">                       
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Select City <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">City</li>
          <li><a href="#">Manchester</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Liverpool</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Newcastle</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Town</li>
          <li><a href="#">Wigan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">St Helens</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Other</li>
          <li><a href="#">Warwick</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Oxford</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cambridge</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Version Dropdown -->
      <div class="btn-group">             
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Version <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">V8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>           
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "selectable?" If an element exists you can select it.  You need to elaborate on your intentions?  Do you mean you want to be able to select 1 item from each drop down before the actual navigation event occurs?

Comment: If above is true, what you're actually looking to do is attach an "on click" event to the navigation list items where "only one may be a given 'selected' class per dropdown column."  Then, once you select additionally from the second column and 2 "selected" id's exist on your page and effect the "navigation" action using both column values?

Comment: consider https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ , the standard bs dropdown menu is simply for navigation, not working as a select.

Comment: @MikeHorstmann yes I wish to be able to select 1 item per dropdown. For example: the current text in dropdown 1 would change from 'Select City' to 'London' if London was selected. I hope that makes more sense. Cheers!

Comment: @GL.awog thanks that answers my question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer posted by "GL.awog" - Consider [silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select), the standard bs dropdown menu is simply for navigation, not working as a select.

The site was easy to follow and I had this working in minutes :)